# Correct use of Ressource Controller in Laravel

Tags: laravel, controller

I use the Laravel Ressource Controller but I am not sure if I use it the right way. I start with a easy view return which I put in the create function. In this view i write a name into a textfield and click the submit button which runs the function index. Defaul index function is only index() I changed it to index(Request $request) because of the post request. But I don't believe that index is the right function for that need. Here is the complete Controller.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $username = $request->username;
    $user = User::where('name', $username)->select('id', 'name')->first();

    return view('invitation.username')->with('user', $user);
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return view('invitation.username');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}
```

Where to put the code? What is the correct function for my needs? Or should I create a new function?

Comment: first show your route

Comment: First and foremost tell us a little bit more about what do you intend to do? `index` is often utilized for a small "home screen" for the whole resource, e.g. to show a table with all users. So `index` might not be the best for you. Based on what you want, it should be a derivative of `show`, or `createWithUser` based on the returned view (which is the same as the one on `create`). If you can provide more info we can help a little better.

Answer (score 0):

Resource controllers may not be the best for this pattern.

- Index - show a listing of the resources for the model associated with the controller
- Create - show the form for creating the model
- Store - Accept the POST request from the Create form
- Show - Show an individual resource
- Edit - Show the form for editing a model
- Update - Accept the PUT request from the editing form to update the model.

For your case, I think the function nomenclature that would be more appropriate would be:

```
public function search()
{
    return view('invitation.search');
}
```

Then to display those results:

```
public function results()
{
    return view('invitation.results')
        ->with('user', User::where('name', request()->input('username'))->first());
}
```

Although this could be expounded and extrapolated out further to add support for additional field searching.